# Sum of certain Group Totals

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports-2010, group-summaries

I'm making a crystal report using Crystal Reports for VS2012 to show the amount of cord ordered to be cut during a date range. I've got everything working except one part and I'm not even sure this is possible.

How the report is set up right now is like this:

1. Group 1(Date) (ex. 03/13/13)

   - Group 2 (Who Ordered) (ex. Dan)

     - ...Details (Including cord length)

       - Length Total (ex. Dan's Total for 3/13/13)
   - Group 2 (ex. Tom)

     - ...Details

       - Length Total (ex. Tom's Total for 3/13/13)
2. Group 1 (ex. 3/14/13)

   - Group 2 (ex. Dan)

     - ...Details

       - Length Total (ex. Dan's Total for 3/14/13)
   - Group 2 (ex. Bob)

     - ...Details

       - Length Total (ex. Bob's Total for 3/14/13)

What I'm wanting to do is at the end be able to have a sum for each of our 3 main people and another sum for any other names in the report footer, so it looks like this:

Total:
Dan: ### (Total of all of Dan's Cord Length totals)
       Tom: ### (Total of all of Tom's Cord Length totals)
       Bob: ### (Total of all of Bob's Cord Length totals)
       Other: ### (Total of all cord cut for people other than Dan, Tom, Bob)

Is there a way to do this, or am I just asking for to much?

Comment: Will there always only be a Dan, Tom, Bob and Other?

Comment: There is a way, it is just a question of how difficult it will be to create.  What the previous comment is getting at is that if you always know you want totals for 3 people, with the rest thrown into an other bucket, there are relatively easy ways to do that.  If the totals you want to see can change, things start getting more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

U can get the sum of 3 people like this :

Insert --> Summary --> GrandTotal

so u can get the sum for all the users

For get the sum of only specific Group

Insert --> Summary --> GroupTotal

Try this...............